# Android camera intent for 3 images destroys and recreates fragment and crashes onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-camera-intent

There are 3 imageviews on which I want to set image captured from camera. Camera intent is fired from a fragment, picture is being captured, but when returned to app fragment gets destroyed and is recreated.

I am saving all 3 image paths in list but since fragment is destroyed list is reinitialized and size of list becomes 0.

The intent fired for camera is:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (getActivity() != null) {
if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        photoPaths.add(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
Uri photoURI=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),"com.example.parking.fileprovider",photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                    }
                }
            }
```

And in onActivityResult the image intent is fetched:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
// here imgCount is for checking number of images captured since I only want to capture 3 images.
if (imgCount == 0) {
bitmap = cropImageForApp(preview1, photoPaths.get(imgCount));
preview1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imgCount++;
                } else if (imgCount == 1) {
bitmap = cropImageForApp(preview2, photoPaths.get(imgCount));
                    preview2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imgCount++;
                } else if(imgCount ==2) {
bitmap =cropImageForApp(preview3,photoPaths.get(imgCount));
preview3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imgCount++;
}
```

Expected Result:The image to be captured and set on imageview.

And the error I am getting is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.parking.vehicleparking/com.parking.vehicleparking.activity.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.parking.vehicleparking/com.parking.vehicleparking.activity.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3697)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.parking.vehicleparking/com.parking.vehicleparking.activity.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4365)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3697) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
>           at com.parking.vehicleparking.fragment.CaptureImageFragment.onActivityResult(CaptureImageFragment.java:143)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
>           at com.parking.vehicleparking.activity.RegisterActivity.onActivityResult(RegisterActivity.java:275)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7341)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4361)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3697) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: Your activity is recreated by the system after every intent. You should override onSaveInstanceState() and recreate the instance state when the system calls onCreateActivity() again.

Comment: @Alex Cohn I saved list in onSaveInstanceState() and retrieved it in onActivityCreated(), but fragment onDestroyView() is called and then fragment's onActivityResult() is called and then first fragment becomes visible. And when continued from 1st fragment 3rd and 4th fragment are overlapped, i.e., both fragments views are visible.

Comment: Right, `onActivityResult()` happens before `onResume()`. The expected fragment may not have been activated yet. Restoring fragments when your app is restarted by system is not an easy task.

Comment: @Alex Cohn So can you suggest a different approach for the issue.

Comment: To keep things simple, `onActivityResult()` should be handled in the activity, not delegated to fragment.

Comment: @Alex Cohn If onActivityResult is triggered from activity then all previous fragments in activity are being destroyed, i.e., the activity is recreated and first fragment is visible.

Comment: The activity is destroyed anyways, that's because the system decides that the Camera app needs maximum resources. It is your responsibility to bring the activity to correct state after it is recreated after the camera intent is completed (or cancelled). This includes restoring the fragments the way you expect them. The catch is that we usually take care of fragments and other state issues in onResume(), but the activity result must be consumed before.

Comment: @Alex Cohn, how to restore all fragments on activity recreation? Is there any documentation or blog that I can follow?

Comment: This has nothing to do with camera or fragments. The point is that Android requires that you restore everything to state exactly same as what you had when onSaveInstanceState() is called.